# Is complement $L = \{ w : |w|_{a} \equiv |w|_{b} \vee |w|_{c} \equiv |w|_{d} \}$ context-free

Tags: regular-languages, context-free, formal-grammars, pumping-lemma, check-my-answer

$L = \{ w : |w|_{a} \equiv |w|_{b} \vee |w|_{c} \equiv |w|_{d} \}$

In my opinion complement of the L language is

$L^{C} = \{ w : |w|_{a} \neq  |w|_{b} \wedge |w|_{c} \neq  |w|_{d} \}$

I choose to Ogden pummping lemma word $s = a^{p}b^{p + p!}c^{p}d^{p + p!}$ and $ p > n$

I would like to distinguish $c ^ {p}$. And then I have to have at least one distinguished symbol and the rest not distinguished and in my opinion it can't be pumped in any case because i can $c^{p}$ pumped to $c^{p + p!}$  so it isn't context-free

Do I think right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I choose to Ogden pumping word $s = a^{p}b^{p + p!}c^{p}d^{p + p!}$ and $ p > n$.

I am afraid you could not show that Ogden's pumping lemma cannot be applied to $s$ since $s$ belongs to the context-free language, $P_1=\{a^{k}b^lc^md^n\mid k\not=l\wedge m\not=n\}$, which is a subset of $L^C$.

Although your approach does not work, your conclusion that $L^C$ isn't context-free is correct.

---

Well, you are quite near the right approach.

Let $P_2=L^C\cap L(a^*c^*b^*d^*)=\{a^{k}c^mb^ld^n\mid k\not=l\wedge m\not=n\}$. We can show word $a^{p}c^{p}b^{p+p!}d^{p + p!}$ cannot be pumped as described in Ogden's lemma for $P_2$ when all of its $a$'s are distinguished. Hence $P_2$ is not context-free. Since $L(a^*c^*b^*d^*)$ is regular, $L^C$ cannot be context-free.

---

**Exercise 1.** Show $P_1$ is context-free. Show $P_3$ is context-free, too where $P_3=\{a^{k}c^md^nb^l\mid k\not=l\wedge m\not=n\}$.

**Exercise 2.** Show $P_2$ is not context-free following the approach given above.

**Exercise 3.** Show the complement of the following language is not context-free, $\{ w : |w|_{a} = |w|_{b} \vee |w|_{c} \not= |w|_{d} \}$.

Comment: Exercise 3.  L^C = |w|_a !=  |w|_b ^ |w|_c =  |w|_d have i right? We can choose word a^pc^pb^(p+p!)d^(p+p!) ?

Comment: It looks like you made a typo since $a^pc^pb^{p+p!}d^{p+p!} \not\in L^C$, which cannot be used to disprove context-freeness. You probably meant $a^pc^pb^{p+p!}d^p$.